# Find and replace in Text Box in Header of Word Doc using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use Powershell to do a find and replace of some text within a Text Box that is within the Header of a Word Document (.docx). I was able to get it working for text outside of the Header but not that within. I think it is failing because I am not correctly accessing the contents of the Text Box, so I added in the final line (before quit and save) to see what the text was but it printed out blank for each of the three Items in my Header. This is my first time using Powershell and I think I have perhaps spent more time learning this and writing it than I will save by using it...

The relevant snippet of the script is below:

```
$word = New-Object -COM "Word.Application";
$word.Visible = $false;
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($FullPath);
$selection = $word.Selection;
$section = $doc.sections.item(1);
$header = $section.headers.Item(3);
$FindText = "Cnnn";
$MatchCase = $False;
$MatchWholeWord = $False;
$MatchWildcards = $False;
$MatchSoundsLike = $False;
$MatchAllWordForms = $False;
$Forward = $True;
$wdFindContinue = 1;
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue;
$Format = $False;
$wdReplaceNone = 0;
$ReplaceAll = 2;
$ReplaceWith = "C" + $newString; 
$a = $header.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith, $ReplaceAll);

Write-Host ("Header is: " + $header.Text);

$doc.Save();
$word.Quit();
```

Comment: Why `$section.headers.Item(3)`? Shouldn't it be `Item(1)`? What pages is the header you're looking for on?

Comment: Hi, @Mathias sorry yes it's on page 1, well all pages actually, I was just trying different things. When I had Item(1) it printed the Header text as a slash - "/"

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your search to the `.TextFrame.TextRange.Find` object from the `TextBox` or any `shape` containing text.
You could try something like this:

```
If ($header.ShapeRange.Count) {
  ForEach ($shp in $header.ShapeRange) {
    If ($shp.TextFrame.HasText) {
      $obj = $shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Find
      $a = $obj.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord,` 
             $MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
             $Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$ReplaceAll)
    }
  }
}
```